# How to set submit sm to let the client use its properties in jamaa smpp to send message?

Tags: c#, smpp

I am using `jamaa-smpp` to send message. It works but the sender id was 00000 instead of the name that I wanted. I put the `TON` and `NPI` for enabling alphanumeric sender in the submit sm as shown in the code below but it still is 00000. I can't link the sm to the client when sending message.

```
 public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void ss_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            var sm = new SubmitSm();


            sm.SourceAddress.Ton = JamaaTech.Smpp.Net.Lib.TypeOfNumber.Aphanumeric;
            sm.SourceAddress.Npi = JamaaTech.Smpp.Net.Lib.NumberingPlanIndicator.ISDN;

            sm.DestinationAddress.Ton = JamaaTech.Smpp.Net.Lib.TypeOfNumber.International;
            sm.DestinationAddress.Npi = JamaaTech.Smpp.Net.Lib.NumberingPlanIndicator.ISDN;

            TextMessage msg = new TextMessage();

            msg.DestinationAddress ="96565565655556"; //Receipient number
            msg.SourceAddress = "NYCOMPANYNAME"; //Originating number

            msg.Text = "text text text text";
            msg.RegisterDeliveryNotification = true; //I want delivery notification for this message


            SmppClient client = GetSmppClient();

            client.BeginSendMessage(msg, SendMessageCompleteCallback, client);
        }


        private void client_ConnectionStateChanged(object sender, ConnectionStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.CurrentState)
            {
                case SmppConnectionState.Closed:
                    //Connection to the remote server is lost
                    //Do something here

                    e.ReconnectInteval = 60000; //Try to reconnect after 1 min
                    break;
                case SmppConnectionState.Connected:
                    //A successful connection has been established
                    break;
                case SmppConnectionState.Connecting:
                    //A connection attemp is still on progress
                    break;
            }
        }
        private SmppClient GetSmppClient()
        {
            SmppClient client = new SmppClient();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(9000);
            SmppConnectionProperties properties = client.Properties;
            properties.SystemID = "id";
            properties.Password = "pass";
            properties.Port = xxxxx; //IP port to use
            properties.Host = "x.x.x.x"; //SMSC host name or IP Address
            properties.SystemType = "SMPP";
            properties.DefaultServiceType = "SMPP";
            client.AutoReconnectDelay = 3000;
            client.KeepAliveInterval = 15000;
            client.Start();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(9000);
            return client;
        }

        private static void SendMessageCompleteCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            try
            {
                SmppClient client = (SmppClient)result.AsyncState;
                client.EndSendMessage(result);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }

    }
```

I expect the sender name to be MYCOMPANYNAME instead of 00000000.

Comment: hello please help

Comment: Please note that not all SMSCs support the alphanumeric sender addresses.You might not be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the 'NPI' to unknown and 'ton' to alphanumeric and

```
client.Properties.SourceAddress = "COMPANYNAME";  
client.SourceAddress.Ton = JamaaTech.Smpp.Net.Lib.TypeOfNumber.Alphanumeric;
client.SourceAddress.Npi=JamaaTech.Smpp.Net.Lib.NumberingPlanIndicator.Unknown;
```

not  msg.SourceAddress = "MYCOMPANYNAME";

hope it helps.please mark if you find this answer useful.

Comment: i tried the correction and the sender was "unknown" is that a code problem or some settings from SMSC side

Comment: kindly set the 'NPI' to unknown and 'ton' to  alphanumeric. Remember that the length of your company name should be 11 characters at max.

Comment: i set the NPI to unknown and it still anonymous

Comment: kindly share your latest code for review and better understanding

Answer (score 0):

the updated code is :

```
{

 protected void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sm = new SubmitSm();
        sm.SourceAddress.Npi = JamaaTech.Smpp.Net.Lib.NumberingPlanIndicator.Unknown;
        sm.SourceAddress.Ton = JamaaTech.Smpp.Net.Lib.TypeOfNumber.Aphanumeric
        sm.DestinationAddress.Ton = JamaaTech.Smpp.Net.Lib.TypeOfNumber.International;
        sm.DestinationAddress.Npi = JamaaTech.Smpp.Net.Lib.NumberingPlanIndicator.Unknown;
        TextMessage msg = new TextMessage();
        msg.DestinationAddress ="123456789"; //Receipient number
        msg.Text = "test test";
        msg.RegisterDeliveryNotification = true; //I want delivery notification for this message
        SmppClient client = GetSmppClient();
        client.BeginSendMessage(msg, SendMessageCompleteCallback, client);
    }


    private void client_ConnectionStateChanged(object sender, ConnectionStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.CurrentState)
        {
            case SmppConnectionState.Closed:
                e.ReconnectInteval = 60000; //Try to reconnect after 1 min
                break;
            case SmppConnectionState.Connected:
                break;
            case SmppConnectionState.Connecting:
                break;
        }
    }
    private SmppClient GetSmppClient()
    {
        SmppClient client = new SmppClient();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(9000);
        SmppConnectionProperties properties = client.Properties;
        properties.SystemID = "xxxxxx";
        properties.Password = "xxxxxx";
        properties.Port = 10000; //IP port to use
        properties.Host = "xx.xx.xx.xx"; //SMSC host name or IP Address
        properties.SystemType = "SMPP";
        properties.DefaultServiceType = "SMPP";
        properties.SourceAddress = "MYCOMPANY";
        properties.AddressNpi = NumberingPlanIndicator.Unknown;
        properties.AddressTon = TypeOfNumber.Aphanumeric;
        properties.DefaultEncoding = DataCoding.Latin1;
        client.AutoReconnectDelay = 3000;
        client.KeepAliveInterval = 15000;
        client.Start();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(9000);
        return client;
    }

    private static void SendMessageCompleteCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            SmppClient client = (SmppClient)result.AsyncState;
            client.EndSendMessage(result);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyTextMessage : TextMessage
{
    protected override SubmitSm CreateSubmitSm(SmppEncodingService smppEncodingService)
    {
        var sm = base.CreateSubmitSm(smppEncodingService);
        sm.SourceAddress.Ton = JamaaTech.Smpp.Net.Lib.TypeOfNumber.Aphanumeric;
        sm.SourceAddress.Npi = JamaaTech.Smpp.Net.Lib.NumberingPlanIndicator.Unknown;
        return sm;
    }
}
```

And

```
 TextMessage msg = new MyTextMessage();
```